# What is the closest fraction (that isn't something like 31415.../1000...) that gets you pretty close to pi?

Tags: irrational-numbers, pi, fractional-part

I'm just wondering what is the closest fraction (question for math nerds and geniuses) that isn't like pi/length-of-pi that gets you relatively close (like accurate to the 20th place) to pi? For example, 22/7 gets you "ok" close (it is 3.14285714), but it's still off by quite a lot. Another example is: 7920/2521 (as mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596347/is-%CF%80-unusually-close-to-7920-2521)). That gives you the result of 3.14161047. That's very good, but still not that close to pi.

EDIT: Just to lesson the challenge, how about accurate to the tenth decimal point ;) (if you can do 20, then go for it!).

If anyone tackles this, I'll thank them a lot!

Comment: $\frac{355}{113}$ works pretty well.

Comment: For a given size denominator, the best rational approximation to $\pi$ (or any real number) is given by simple continued fraction expansion.

Comment: Yeah well nothing's really 'close' to $\pi$ if you don't have a specific error in mind.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulae_involving_%CF%80#Infinite_series

Comment: another useful one, with quick convergence, is $$\pi^2 = 6\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}$$

Comment: @JohnDouma Wow! Never seen it but wow!

Comment: @user3576467 It's easy to remember because you remember the odd numbers 11, 33 and 55. You split them down the middle and I hope it's obvious which one goes on top.

Comment: If you don't want a huge fraction, but at least 5 to 6 (depending if you round/truncate) decimal places of accuracy, *355/113* gets you to 3.141592920353982

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rational approximations $\frac{p}{q}$ to $\pi$ that you get from truncating the [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) get you about twice as many digits as you might expect, and are about as good as it is possible to get: they satisfy (and this is a general property of continued fractions)

$$\left| \pi - \frac{p}{q} \right| < \frac{1}{q^2}$$

The first one that is accurate to $10$ digits, including $3$, is

$$\frac{104348}{33215} = 3.141592653 \color{red}{0119 \dots}$$

and note that $q$ itself is only $5$ digits long.

Comment: Using a five digit value of $q$, $\frac{312689}{99532}$ seems to be slightly better.

Comment: Yes, but it also has a bigger numerator and denominator.

Comment: I totally agree with you, for sure.